# Do I need a istio sidecar proxy at client end for routing rules to be applied?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I have couple of services named `svc A`  and `svc B` with request flow as follows:

```
svc A --> svc B
```

I have injected sidecar with `svc B` and then added the routing rules via `VirtualServices` object as:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: b
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
  - b.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: b.default.svc.cluster.local
    fault:
      abort:
        percentage:
          value: 100
        httpStatus: 403
```

These rules are only applied when `svc A` has a sidecar istio proxy. Which makes me think if we need to have istio proxy on the client side as well? I was expecting that the service for which I added rules should **only** have the sidecar. I can't think of any technical requirement to have it along side `svc B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Service A needs a sidecar. It's confusing I admit, but the way to think of the VirtualService resource is "where do I find the backends I want to talk to and what service should they appear to provide me?" A's sidecar is its helper which does things on its behalf like load-balancing, and in your case fault injection (Service B is reliable; it's Service A that wants it to seem unreliable).

The comments that A and B both need sidecars in order to communicate at all aren't correct (unless you want mTLS), but if you want the mesh to provide additional services to A, then A needs a sidecar.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should inject sidecar proxy in service A as well. then only the two services can communicate with each other through proxies

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know the technical requirement behind it?

Comment: In istio enabled services the traffic goes through sidecar proxy. if the proxy is not injected then the service cant communicate with another service

Comment: Makes sense. But incoming requests to `svc B` are going through the sidecar proxy and I would expect it to intercept and apply the rules before forwarding it to the given service. I don't see a need of sidecar at `svc A` for this. For polices I would expect that but not for routing rules.

Answer (score 0):

First go ahead and run:

```
gcloud container clusters describe [Your-Pod-Name] | grep -e clusterIpv4Cidr -e servicesIpv4Cidr
```

This will give you two IP addresses. Add these into your deployment yaml like shown below (REPLACING THE IP ADDRESSES WITH YOURS)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: [Your-Pod-Name]
  annotations:
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges: 10.32.0.0/14,10.35.240.0/20
```

This allows internet connection to your services.